# Changing color of the image defined inside <GroundOverlay> attribute of KML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, kml

I can't find a satisfying answer if is it possible to change the color of the **img_097686.png** image via Google Maps Web API. I'm still unsuccessful in getting this code to work as hoped.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <name>097686</name>
    <GroundOverlay>
        <name>RF Analysis</name>
        <color>6eff80ff</color> <!-- I want to change a color to this one -->
        <Icon>
            <href>img_097686.png</href>
            <viewBoundScale>0.90</viewBoundScale>
        </Icon>
        ...
```

Google Earth has no problem to display an image in color defined inside `<color>` tag.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, here's my code in more readable format

```
    $.ajax({
        url: subdomain + '/Map/GetKmlFileId',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { deviceCode: obj.Code },
        success: function (data) {
            kmlFileId = 'http://HOST/KmlHandler.ashx?id=' + data; //KmlHandler returns a real *.kml file
        } 
    });     

    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlFileId, {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: true
    });
    layer.setMap(map._gmap);
```

Comment: What you want to do is probably not possible through the Google Maps Web API, but is probably possible.  How are you displaying the KML?

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, here is my code snippet of using of the KML `$.ajax({
      url: subdomain + '/Map/GetKmlFileId',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { deviceCode: obj.Code },
      success: function (data) {
       kmlFileId = 'http://HOST/KmlHandler.ashx?id=' + data;
      } //KmlHandler returns a real *.kml file
     });     

     var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlFileId, {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: true
     });
     layer.setMap(map._gmap);` Is there any solution how is possible to do it?

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments.  Edit your question to address any comments.

Comment: According to the [Supported KML elements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements) in the documentation of Google Maps JavaScript API, the KML parser generally silently ignores XML tags it does not understand Placemarks, Icons, Folders, Styles for polylines and polygons, including color, fill, and opacity and etc. And if you check the table KML elements in the above link, the color part is not supported in the API.